# Pixabay API HTTP redirection and Mixed Content error

Tags: javascript, typescript, https, fetch, pixabay

When I fetch images from the [Pixabay API](https://pixabay.com/api/docs/):

```js
fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api?key=${API_KEY}&per_page=7`)
```

I get the `Mixed Content` error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-page.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://pixabay.com/api/?key=xxx&per_page=7'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Which I don't understand, since I call `https://pixabay.com` from `https://my-page.com`. After inspecting the Network tab in the console, I see that there is 3 requests:

[image]

1. The initial request that responds with a `301 Redirect` to `http://pixabay.com`
2. The second request `http://pixabay.com` that responds with a `307 Internal Redirect` to `https://pixabay.com`
3. Finally the last request `https://pixabay.com` that responds with a `200`

**Why all this redirects? Do I miss something obvious?
How to make the Pixabay API work properly with HTTPS?**

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: I think I solved it by adding a `/` at the end of the URL (after `api/`). It's been a while, I forget if I solved it this way. Let me know, I will post an answer if needed.